# cygwin - Running msbuild with switches

Tags: bash, msbuild, cygwin

I'm trying to improve our build automation using bash. My shell scripting leaves a lot to be desired but essentially I want to be able to use a bash shell script to run `MSBuild.exe` passing in certain build switches. So in `myscript.sh` there's a line :

```
C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe /maxcpucount:8 /verbosity:q /p:Configuration=Debug C:/Myfolder/Main.sln
```

This fails due to the `/p:Configuration=Debug`. I can say that with certainty as without it the execution of `MSBuild.exe` works.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Have you considered Powershell as an alternative to BASH?  we've implemented it and it's pretty killer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out it was due to

/p:

When using /property:Configuration=Debug it works.

Thanks for the help.

Tim